# IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea/Data' to 'Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data'

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mono, macos-high-sierra

I have problem using unity on mac when i want to build apk.. i've searched in many forums but coudnt get any solution. Anyone know what to do?

Here are the errors:

```
    IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea/Data' to 'Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data'.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PrepareUnityResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:186)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: Please format your post according to [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: done. Thank you @MarcinPietraszek